# Floating action button on other app and in launcher

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have been searching for a floating circle button that I can interact with everywhere like luncher or in whatsapp and etc ...

so far I only found the action button witch introduced in lollipop. this question may has been asked before and i didn't know the right terminology to search in google. I have seen other apps uses these kind of button. so please help me out here

how can I place a floating button on screen which appear every where. something like AssistiveTouch menu button in IOS which can be dragged everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i found the solution with this awesome repo.
use this library :) ===>
[Floating button in github](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView)

here is how it look like :

[image: floating button]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check Floating Action Button for your first use case.
Here is the github link: [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)

I haven't come across movable button for android so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different libraries that do just that:

- https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button
- https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

---

If you like those, maybe check at these other [awesome libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui)!

Comment: in the first look this is not what i am looking for. i want the floating action button become like AssistiveTouch of IOS. to be appear on any app.